# How to add element to php array without it showing as a new array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The intention with the below code is to extract messages from a mysql table, and put each of them inside ONE array with {} around each output. Each output consists of various parameters as you can see, and is an array in itself. 
What the code does is that each time the loop is processed, in the JSON array that this later is converted into, it wraps the output in []´s, hence it´s now a new array which is created.
What I get is:

```
[{"sender":"ll","message":"blah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:04","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"},{"sender":"kk","message":"blahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:23","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"},{"sender":"ll","message":"blahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:47","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"}],[{"sender":"ll","message":"blahblahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:04","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"92337321312222016034304"},{"sender":"kk","message":"blahblahblahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:44:05","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"92337321312222016034304"}]]
```

And what I want is:

```
[{"sender":"ll","message":"blah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:04","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"},{"sender":"kk","message":"blahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:23","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"},{"sender":"ll","message":"blahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:47","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"32629016712222016034323"}],{"sender":"ll","message":"blahblahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:43:04","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"92337321312222016034304"},{"sender":"kk","message":"blahblahblahblahblah","timestamp":"2016-12-21 14:44:05","username":"","msgtype":"","threadid":"92337321312222016034304"}]
```

How do I proceed to get the right result here?

```
$data = array ();
foreach($threads as $threadid){
$sql = ("SELECT sender,message,timestamp,username,msgtype,threadid FROM    Messages WHERE  threadid = '$threadid' AND subject = '' AND timestamp >    '$newtimestamp' ORDER BY timestamp");
$arrayOfObjects = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$data[] = $$arrayOfObjects;
}
```

And FYI, $threadid is another array containing... threadids, and the loop correctly fetches these one by one, that´s not where the problem is.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: *... and put each of them inside ONE array with {} around each output.*, are you trying to get json string?

Comment: can you specify what you mean with _"inside ONE array with {} around each output"_? Where/How do you want to see those brackets? As Json maybe? As {} indicates an object, not an array, it's a bit confusing what you want.

Comment: your need to define empty array var outside from foreach, and push array content inside of foreach.

Comment: I think you mean that: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `O(N)` database queries, consider doing just `O(1)` using an `IN` expression in your where clause. No need for a `foreach` loop and you'll get all your data in one array.

```
SELECT ... FROM Messages WHERE threadid IN (1, 2, 3, ...) AND ...
```

You might have to use a prepared statement for that.

Comment: So "WHERE threadid IN ('$threadid')"? Then I just get [] as output.

Comment: `IN` expects a comma separated list of ALL ids.

Comment: So then this method won´t work since the threadids need to be extracted from the mysql database. Or is there a way to generate such a comma separated list inside php instead of an array, and use it the way I´m doing it?

Comment: In your example the ids seem to be in `$threads`. Best use a prepared statement, read the documentation on who to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but that´s a whole other world for me, prepared statements, that I will be digging into later. I will try to figure out how to do this the way Jeff is suggesting instead.

Comment: Well, I decided to give your suggestion one more try, and managed to do it in a none prepared way. I´m aware that this is supposed to be risky, but so far this project just needs to work, then have the php codes updated to safer versions, and then go live:

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.
You had `FETCH_ASSOC`, which will return an array of associative arrays.
`FETCH_OBJ`will return an array ob stdObjects.

Also you reassigned `$array` to itself when doing `$array[] = $array;`..

```
$data = array();
foreach($threads as $threadid){
    $sql = ("SELECT sender,message,timestamp,username,msgtype,threadid FROM    Messages WHERE  threadid = '$threadid' AND subject = '' AND timestamp >    '$newtimestamp' ORDER BY timestamp");
    //                                             here it is:
    $arrayOfObjects = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $data[] = $arrayOfObjects;
}

// now you can encode that as json and show it:
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: It´s indeed a JSON string I´m aiming for here, sorry to not be more clear about that.

Comment: I tried all the amendments but I get the same result. I´ve also updated the initial question so you can see what it is that I´m talking about.

Comment: the difference between what you _get_ and what you _want_ is that you still reassign `$array` to itself

Comment: You mean: $array[] = $array;? Well, I´ve changed the code in the script to exactly what you said but the output look the same.

Comment: Ok, I´ve updated the main message to reflect the changes made based upon your advise.

Answer (score 0):

@akuhn

Well, I decided to give your suggestion one more try, and managed to do it in a none prepared way. I´m aware that this is supposed to be risky, but so far this project just needs to work, then have the php codes updated to safer versions, and then go live. It works, so thanks a bunch!

```
$sql = ("SELECT sender,message,timestamp,username,msgtype,threadid FROM Messages WHERE threadid IN ('" . implode("','",$threadid) . "') AND subject = '' AND timestamp > '$newtimestamp' ORDER BY timestamp");
$data = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```